# Convert unknown Hex digits to a Longitude and Latitude

Tags: c, binary, hex, coordinates, latitude-longitude

```
F3 c8 42 14 - latitude //05.13637° should be nearby this coordinate
5d a4 40 b2  - longitude //100.47629° should be nearby this coordinate
```

this is the hex data i get from GPS device, how to convert to readable coordinate?
i don't have any manual document.please help.thanks

```
    22 00 08 00 c3 80 00 20 00 dc f3 c8 42 14 5d a4 40 b2 74 5d 34 4e 52 30 39
47 30 35 31 36 34 00 00 00
```

this is my full bytes i received,but the engineer told me that  F3 c8 42 14 is latitude and 5d a4 40 b2 is longitude

Comment: I've edited the title and added a few other tags to attract a wider audience, since you'll be better off with more eyeballs.  In particular, the C tag should get you many hard-core experts, one of whom might have the winning idea.

Comment: I'm gonna lose my sleep over this one. @Anthor, could you give us the model number or something from the GPS module?

Comment: [This answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5123735/181638) seemed to use more than simply the hex encoding of position...  But I can't understand how he arrived at his constants.

Comment: @Khanal:this is an china GPS device,so,dont have any model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the values are in 32-bit floating point. However, the bytes are slightly shifted in the stream that you show. Taking longitude first: 100.47629 in 32-bit floating point is 42C8F3DC these are bytes 10 through 13 in your stream (Least significant byte first).
For latitude 5.13637 in 32-bit floating point is 40A45D24 these are bytes 14 through 17 but it's 40A45D14 in the byte stream so it's off a little in the least significant decimal digit (Again, it's least significant byte first).

Answer (score 4):

I worked with a Motorola GPS module once and the documentation said that the two hexes represented int types.

In your case, you might want to look at the documentation as well. If you know the model number, you can just google it.
Here is the documentation link for the motorola GPS I used.

[Motorola GPS Module](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wa5rrn.com%2FGPS%2520Other%2FMotorola%2520M12%2Fgpsusersguidev5chap3.pdf&ei=xC3-UNiyOozy9gTYg4GoCw&usg=AFQjCNErqt-X5c-1TUHiEh5up6DmXQ_FNA&sig2=qu51qOx7jp8yMKP1tqp4mw&bvm=bv.41248874,d.eWU)

I also took the liberty to do some calculations for you. If your lattitude was indeed

```
0x1442c8f3
```

(endianness does make a difference here). The integer equivalent is

```
339921139
```

in decimal system. If you divide that by 3600000 milliarcseconds 
(where 1 deg = 60 min = 60 * 60 s = 60*60*1000 ms) you get

```
94.4225386
```

deg, which is close to your expectations. There isn't enough data to validate it but I believe most of the GPS modules return the milliarcseconds for both latitude and longitude.)

Comment: Nice observation! (these are likely fixed point).  However, your intermediate results seem incorrect?  By my calculation 0x1442c8f3 is 339921139 (base 10).  Also, 3,600,000 milli-arcseconds is 60*60*1000.

Comment: The approach to latitude doesn't seem to carry over for longitude.  Assuming little endian representation, we get 0xb240a45d.  If this is a *signed* long, then this would be negative.  But since the position is E, it should be +.  So now assuming this is actually an *unsigned* long, we get the integer value as 2990580829.  Dividing again by 3,600,000 gives 830.71, a bit further away from expectation.

Comment: Sorry, I am going to have to edit it. You are right 339921139 base 10 was what I got. I am still getting used to this dual monitor rig and I copied and pasted the wrong numbers. I will fix it now. And I did get 3600000 by doing 60*60*1000 but got a little overexcited and messed that one up since I got amazing close to the expected result. :)

Comment: No worries -- I got quite excited also by the fixed point observation.  But have a look at the second comment.  Not sure the same approach works for longitude...

Comment: How is 94.4225386 close to 5.13637 degrees? Also you can't have a latitude greater than 90 degrees.

Comment: If it is unsigned, then either Southpole or Northpole would have to be 0. If Southpole is 0, then 94.4335386 S is 4.4335386 N. Again, these are speculations unless we have documentation. This is more along the lines of reverse engineering.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the hex codes represent unencrypted 32-bit floating point numbers (they might not do), you could try reading them into a C program and printing them out using `printf("%f")`.

Don't forget that the words could have both endianness, i.e. the first one could be `F3 C8 42 14` or `14 42 C8 F3` (bytes reversed).

Try it both ways and see if you get anything useful.

I wasn't able to get anything quickly from [this online floating point calculator here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/index.xhtml).

---

**Edit:**

Building on Khanal's answer, this link to [Latitude/Longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709#Latitude) suggests that the numbers are indeed fixed point and explains the sign convention.

Perhaps more useful for the calculations is [HexIt](http://www.wfwsoftware.com/hexit.html), which allows choosing from a variety of C data types, both integer and floating point, as well as flipping back and forth between little and big endian representations.