# Convert hex to latitude longitude from dashcam .MOV file

Tags: gps, hex, latitude-longitude

I have an OEM dashcam that saves videos in .MOV format. I want to extract the embedded gps data from the video files programmatically. Upon opening the .mov file in a hex editor I found data packets with `freeGPS` headers and I can confirm that for my 7 seconds sample video there are 7 packets so I know this where the gps data comes from.

I already found the date and time but I got stuck with converting the hex values to latitude longitude. Below are the hex values and their equivalent coordinates when extracted using Registrator Viewer.

273108AC1C7996**404E**,0D022B873EA3C7**4045**   -   14.637967,121.041475
516B9A771C7996**404E**,0D022B873EA3C7**4045**   -   14.637963,121.041475
B9FC87F41B7996**404E**,52499D803EA3C7**4045**   -   14.637955,121.041472
B9FC87F41B7996**404E**,52499D803EA3C7**4045**   -   14.637955,121.041472
B459F5B91A7996**404E**,C442AD693EA3C7**4045**   -   14.637935,121.041460
1DEBE2361A7996**404E**,ACADD85F3EA3C7**4045**   -   14.637927,121.041455
08CE19511A7996**404E**,4FD1915C3EA3C7**4045**   -   14.637928,121.041453

The bolded bytes directly translates to @N and @E so I think they are not part of the conversion. I already tried the below answers but I did not succeed in getting the correct coordinates.

[How to convert GPS Longitude and latitude from hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355604/how-to-convert-gps-longitude-and-latitude-from-hex)

[How to convert my binary (hex) data to latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122383/how-to-convert-my-binary-hex-data-to-latitude-and-longitude)

I already sent an email to the dashcam provider asking for their protocol documentation but it does not look like they have one since they sent Registrator Viewer when I asked for their own video player.

I will also include the first `freeGPS` packet in case I am looking at the wrong place.

00 00 80 00 **66 72 65 65 47 50 53** 20 98 00 00 00 78 2E 78 78 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 30 30 30 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 **03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 27 00 00 00** 41 00 00 00 **27 31 08 AC 1C 79 96 40 4E** 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 **0D 02 2B 87 3E A3 C7 40 45** 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8F C2 F5 28 5C 8F E2 3F 48 E1 7A 14 AE 07 68 40 **11 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 14 00 00 00** 76 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 DE 00 00 00 4D 00 00 00 49 00 00 00 4F 00 00 00 2D 00 00 00 2B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Data in bold extracted in order : freeGPS, time, latitude@N?, longitude@E?, date

I can confirm that time and date are correct. The speed is supposed to be 1km/h but I can't also find that.

Thanks in advance for those who can help.

EDIT:
Here is the link for the test video. [Test Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-lx8ZE4hgW1ODJaRUIxQUJ2TDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have a look at [ExifTool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), perhaps it can extract GPS information from video.

Comment: I already played around with exiftool but according to the developer himself this is currently not supported from here [http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=7127.0](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=7127.0)

Comment: Please post a sample file - thanks

Comment: Hi @MarkusSchumann I added the link above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how helpful this is but if you convert the hex string (including the 0x40 at the end) into a little endian IEEE-754 double precision real, then you get approximately 100X the lat/lon.

In C, I did something like

```
printf( "%f\n", *(double*)"\x27\x31\x08\xAC\x1C\x79\x96\x40" );
printf( "%f\n", *(double*)"\x0D\x02\x2B\x87\x3E\xA3\xC7\x40" );
```

and got out

```
1438.278000
12102.488500
```

#### Update thanks to @[TDG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426328/tdg)

If the `1438.278` is interpreted as 14 degrees 38.278 minutes then you get a decimal value of `14.6379666666666667`. If `12102.4885` is interpreted as 121 degrees and 2.4885 minutes, the decimal equivalent is `121.041475`.

Some example C code to do this

```
#include<stdio.h>
double convert( double input ) {
  int i = input/100;
  return ( input - i*100 ) / 60 + i;
}
int main(){
  printf( "%f\n", convert( *(double*)"\x27\x31\x08\xAC\x1C\x79\x96\x40" ) );
  printf( "%f\n", convert( *(double*)"\x0D\x02\x2B\x87\x3E\xA3\xC7\x40" ) );
}
```

Comment: The difference between the actual lat lon from the ones computed using this method is significantly large.

Comment: I think @ceilingcat is right - read 1438.278 as 14 degrees 38 minutes 27.8 seconds.

Comment: Thank you @ceilingcat and @TDG! PS: I also need help in finding the speed and bearing within this hex data it is supposed to be 1km/h and 192.

Comment: I think that the speed is given in m/s - meters per second, not kmh. Don't know about the heading.

Comment: @RioMarieA.Callos I got a bearing of about 209.43 degrees from true north but I may have picked different points than you. `209.43 ~ 90+atan2( second_latitude-first_latitude, second_longitude-first_longitude ) * 180/pi` To estimate speed, one needs at least two timestamps and two waypoints.

Comment: It should be in the hex data itself particularly this part 8F C2 F5 28 5C 8F E2 3F 48 E1 7A 14 AE 07 68 40. I think already found the speed in km/h (first 8 bytes) using @ceilingcat's method. Now I only need the bearing which has the value of 192.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://sergei.nz/extracting-gps-data-from-viofo-a119-and-other-novatek-powered-cameras/) explanation of GPS data format, worked for me.

```
        public static ViofoGpsPoint Parse(uint offset, uint size, byte[] file)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        Array.Copy(file, offset, data, 0, size);

        uint pos = 0;

        uint size1 = Box.ReadUintBE(data, pos); pos += 4;
        string type = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, (int)pos, 4); pos += 4;
        string magic = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, (int)pos, 4); pos += 4;

        if (size != size1 || type != "free" || magic != "GPS ")
            return null;

        ViofoGpsPoint gps = new ViofoGpsPoint();

        //# checking for weird Azdome 0xAA XOR "encrypted" GPS data. 
        //This portion is a quick fix.
        uint payload_size = 254;
        if (data[pos] == 0x05)
        {
            if (size < 254)
                payload_size = size;

            byte[] payload = new byte[payload_size];

            pos += 6; //???
            for (int i = 0; i < payload_size; i++)
            {
                payload[i] = (byte)(file[pos + i] ^ 0xAA);
            }
        }
        else if ((char)data[pos] == 'L')
        {
            const uint OFFSET_V2 = 48, OFFSET_V1 = 16; 
            pos = OFFSET_V2;

            //# Datetime data
            int hour = (int)Box.ReadUintLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            int minute = (int)Box.ReadUintLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            int second = (int)Box.ReadUintLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            int year = (int)Box.ReadUintLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            int month = (int)Box.ReadUintLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            int day = (int)Box.ReadUintLE(data, pos); pos += 4;

            try { gps.Date = new DateTime(2000 + year, month, day, hour, minute, second); }
            catch (Exception err) { Debug.WriteLine(err.ToString()); return null; }

            //# Coordinate data
            char active = (char)data[pos]; pos++;
            gps.IsActive = (active == 'A');

            gps.Latitude_hemisphere = (char)data[pos]; pos++;
            gps.Longtitude_hemisphere = (char)data[pos]; pos++;
            gps.Unknown = data[pos]; pos++;

            float lat = Box.ReadFloatLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            gps.Latitude = FixCoordinate(lat, gps.Latitude_hemisphere);

            float lon = Box.ReadFloatLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            gps.Longtitude = FixCoordinate(lon, gps.Longtitude_hemisphere);

            gps.Speed = Box.ReadFloatLE(data, pos); pos += 4;
            gps.Bearing = Box.ReadFloatLE(data, pos); pos += 4;

            return gps;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// # Novatek stores coordinates in odd DDDmm.mmmm format
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="coord"></param>
    /// <param name="hemisphere"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static double FixCoordinate(double coord, char hemisphere)
    {
        double minutes = coord % 100.0;
        double degrees = coord - minutes;

        double coordinate = degrees / 100.0 + (minutes / 60.0);
        if (hemisphere == 'S' || hemisphere == 'W')
            return -1 * (coordinate);
        else
            return (coordinate);
    }
```

Comment: What is the definition of the 'FixCoordinate' function?

Comment: Added 'FixCoordinate' function - it adjust format to standard 'double' from odd DDDmm.mmmm The whole project is in: [link](https://github.com/zbarjevsky/.NET-Projects/tree/master/DashCamGPSView/GpsInfoParser/NovatekViofo)